# How should we understand "boasted an amenity" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Rasputin, the gaudy restaurant/nightclub on Coney Island Avenue, ***boasted an amenity*** that was certain to raise questions about security with even the most hardened Manhattan restaurant patron -- toilet stalls with bulletproof doors.

I think 'boast' here means 'have', but I'm not sure how "have an amenity" can make sense in the context. Why does "have an amenity" raise questions about security? Can someone help to explain what the whole sentence is trying to convey? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An amenity is "a desirable or useful feature or facility of a building".  So you might say "The house has many amenities, including a home gym and an outside pool".  These are quite good, so we might say "The house boasts many amenities, including a home gym...".  (There is a little personification here)

We sometimes say "the amenities" as a euphemism for "toilets": "I'm just going to use the amenities..."

Now bulletproof doors are a surprising feature.  You would only need them if you expected people to be shooting at the toilets. This is why it raises questions about security:

> Why do you need bulletproof doors?  Do you get many shootings in your toilets?

Comment: So, you meant that "the amenity" refers to " toilet stalls with bulletproof doors"?

Comment: If so, why has it been put at the end of the sentence? Is it clearer to put: boasted an amenity (toilet stalls with bulletproof doors) that ... ? Is there any special reason or just a stylish?

Comment: Purely styistic reasons.  The original version reads much better.  You don't want to put the topic of the sentence in parenthesis, which indicates to the reader that it is additional and non-essential information.

Comment: I think we may often use 'boast' in a sarcastic way.